# Secure LDAP works with PHP CLI but not through apache

Tags: php, apache, ldap, command-line-interface

I am trying to authenticate over secure LDAP against my Debian server from another Debian box.

The following code works from the command line (prints "Success"):

```
if($ldap = ldap_connect('ldaps://myserver.tld'))
{
  ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
  $bind = ldap_bind($ldap,'cn=admin,dc=myserver,dc=tld','mypassword');
  print ldap_error($ldap);
}
```

...pulling the same file via Apache/mod_php prints "Can't contact LDAP server"

There is another similar question here on stackoverflow, but its answers did not work for me. I have already tried using the same php.ini for apache that was used for the cli, but the problem stayed the same.

Comment: are you sure that the CLI and the apache module are using the same LDAP module?  Have a look at the phpinfo() output on both sides and look for ldaps support

Comment: They do use the same module...

Comment: In a ```phpinfo()```-output, can you find ```ldaps``` in the *Protocols*-Section in both CLI and apache-module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve my own issue and I do want to share my solution with you:

I am using a self-signed certificate for my LDAP-server, so it was neccessary to create my own ca-certificate and import it to the client's certificate store to establish trust. 
While I ran the above script from the cli as user **root**, apache runs as **www-data**.
My selfmade ca-certifictate's permissions were set to **400**, its user to **root**, thus only root could read it.

This prevented php on apache (running as www-data) from estabishing a connection to my LDAP-server. As soon as I had changed the ca-certificate's permissions to **444**, everything worked like a charm...

Answer (score 3):

We just had this problem happen. It turned out that all we had to do was restart Apache.

I have no idea what the cause was (I don't administer the server) but it was most likely security updates.

Comment: I was trying for an hour to figure it out - thought your answer was just lazy administration.  Turns out I'm lazy too and tried it as a last ditch effort, and it worked!  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Strangely, the right solution for me... Turns out "sudo apachectl restart" on macOS worked. Thanks!